# Add Column in r data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to add a new column to an existing data table in `r`. When I run the following command with a specific row index it works perfectly:

```
testdf[1,"Date Time":=as.POSIXct(paste(testdf[1,"Date Local"], testdf[1,"Time Local"]), 
  format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]
```

However, if if remove the row index to have it generate results for all rows, it simply produces a new column filled with all `NA` values.

```
testdf[,"Date Time":=as.POSIXct(paste(testdf[,"Date Local"], testdf[,"Time Local"]), 
  format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]
```

Can anyone spot what the issue is?

Note that if `testdf` is stored as a data frame the following command also works perfectly and generates a full column of results:

```
tempdf$Date.Time<- as.POSIXct(paste(tempdf$Date.Local, tempdf$Time.Local), 
  format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. This should be ```testdf[, Date_Time := as.POSIXct(paste(`Date Local`, `Time Local`), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")]``` And you should really try keeping your column names without spaces. Also, perhaps take a look [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/) for some data.table vignettes.

Comment: Thanks for your response David! When I try the line of code you suggested I still get all NA values. Does it make a difference that 'Date Local' and 'Time Local' are initially stored as character classes?

Comment: Never mind, it works! I thought the back ticks were single quotes.

Comment: You need the back ticks because you have spaces in your column names. If you had a normal column names you would just write them as is without quotes.